# Countif in summary sheet not matching raw data sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a raw data sheet of parcel IDs in column A, you can see that there are 2520 total rows. Column B shows landowners so some landowners have more than 1 parcel id (col A):

[image]

So my second screenshot below shows me doing a countif of parcel ID based on landowner name from first sheet:

[image]

There are 1506 unique landowners, and I brought in the count of parcels per landowner. Based on first sheet, it should be 2520, but its 2886.

Why is the sum not 2520?

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you share a sample file?

Comment: @Harun24hr so the weird thing is if I copy and paste this data into a new sheet, the counts work. Any ideas what could be causing that?

Comment: Can you provide your sample file (please remove any sensitive information) not just the image of the sheet that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result.Including a sample file will greatly increase your chances of receiving a targeted solution.

Comment: It seems to me that you duplicated the count by applying `countif` to every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a fundamental assumption you are making that is off.  You need to share some data or perform additional tests yourself.

See if the following formula returns the expected result or a clue to your issue.

It counts each unique non-null value under Landowner which presumably should be capture all parcel IDs.

```
=QUERY(B:B, "SELECT B,
   COUNT(B) WHERE B IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY B LABEL COUNT(B)
   'Parcels'",1)
```

You can adjust it to include the total as well:

```
=LET(range,B:B, 
  p,QUERY(range, "SELECT B,
    COUNT(B) WHERE B IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY B LABEL COUNT(B) 'Parcels'",1),
 { "Total:", SUM(INDEX(p,,2));"",""; p })
```

You can also verify your value counts for the two columns using:

```
={ "", "Count Values", "Count w/out Dupes";
   "Col A", COUNTA(A2:A),
      COUNTA(UNIQUE(A2:A));
   "Col B", COUNTA(B2:B),
       COUNTA(UNIQUE(B2:B)) }
```

- Assumes labels in `A1:B1` but change ranges to `A:A` and `B:B` if not the case.